# Mermaid class diagram hide/conceal certain nodes and links/edgePaths

Tags: css, svg, markdown, mermaid

I want to create a mermaid class diagram in a github `.md` file where in I can hide/conceal certain nodes and paths/links from that node using CSS.

#### What I want?

I want the following where the node for the Zebra is concealed and the arrow path/link from it is also concealed. But the sibling Lion class and it's link is 100% opacity.

[image]

#### What I have tried:

I was able to hide nodes using the [cssClass feature](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/classDiagram.html#styling-a-node) as below:

````
// CSS
<style>
  .conceal {
    opacity: 20% !important;
  }
</style>

// ```mermaid
   classDiagram
       Animal <|--|> Zebra
       Animal <|--|> Lion
       cssClass "Zebra" conceal
// ```
````

This produces the following chart where Zebra is concealed while lion is not

[image]

However the path from the Zebra is still 100% opacity.

To fix the opacity of the edgePath I tried the following:

```css
  .edgePaths:has(~g>g.conceal) {
    opacity: 20% !important;
  }
```

````
// CSS
<style>
  .conceal {
    opacity: 20% !important;
  }
  .edgePaths:has(~g>g.conceal) {
    opacity: 20% !important;
  }
</style>


//```mermaid
classDiagram
    Animal <|--|> Zebra
    Animal <|--|> Lion
    cssClass "Zebra" conceal
//```
````

**Note:** the `has` css selector does not work in Firefox yet.

However, this made both paths from Animal have the lowered opacity as can be seen (in Chrome):

[image]

Here is the SVG as example:

```
<svg aria-labelledby="chart-title-mermaid-1671893404869 chart-desc-mermaid-1671893404869" role="img" viewBox="0.000003814697265625 0.00000286102294921875 170.4431915283203 195.19317626953125" style="max-width: 170.4431915283203px;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" id="mermaid-1671893404869">
    <style>
        .conceal {
            opacity: 20% !important;
        }
        .edgePaths:has(~g>g.conceal) {
            opacity: 20% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <title id="chart-title-mermaid-1671893404869">
    </title>
    <desc id="chart-desc-mermaid-1671893404869">
    </desc>
    <style>
        #mermaid-1671893404869 {font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;fill:#333;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .error-icon{fill:#552222;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .error-text{fill:#552222;stroke:#552222;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edge-thickness-normal{stroke-width:2px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edge-thickness-thick{stroke-width:3.5px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edge-pattern-solid{stroke-dasharray:0;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edge-pattern-dashed{stroke-dasharray:3;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edge-pattern-dotted{stroke-dasharray:2;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .marker{fill:#333333;stroke:#333333;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .marker.cross{stroke:#333333;}#mermaid-1671893404869 svg{font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 g.classGroup text{fill:#9370DB;fill:#131300;stroke:none;font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 g.classGroup text .title{font-weight:bolder;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .nodeLabel,#mermaid-1671893404869 .edgeLabel{color:#131300;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edgeLabel .label rect{fill:#ECECFF;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .label text{fill:#131300;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edgeLabel .label span{background:#ECECFF;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .classTitle{font-weight:bolder;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .node rect,#mermaid-1671893404869 .node circle,#mermaid-1671893404869 .node ellipse,#mermaid-1671893404869 .node polygon,#mermaid-1671893404869 .node path{fill:#ECECFF;stroke:#9370DB;stroke-width:1px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .divider{stroke:#9370DB;stroke:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 g.clickable{cursor:pointer;}#mermaid-1671893404869 g.classGroup rect{fill:#ECECFF;stroke:#9370DB;}#mermaid-1671893404869 g.classGroup line{stroke:#9370DB;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .classLabel .box{stroke:none;stroke-width:0;fill:#ECECFF;opacity:0.5;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .classLabel .label{fill:#9370DB;font-size:10px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .relation{stroke:#333333;stroke-width:1;fill:none;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .dashed-line{stroke-dasharray:3;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #compositionStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .composition{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #compositionEnd,#mermaid-1671893404869 .composition{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #dependencyStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .dependency{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #dependencyStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .dependency{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #extensionStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .extension{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #extensionEnd,#mermaid-1671893404869 .extension{fill:#333333!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #aggregationStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .aggregation{fill:#ECECFF!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #aggregationEnd,#mermaid-1671893404869 .aggregation{fill:#ECECFF!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #lollipopStart,#mermaid-1671893404869 .lollipop{fill:#ECECFF!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 #lollipopEnd,#mermaid-1671893404869 .lollipop{fill:#ECECFF!important;stroke:#333333!important;stroke-width:1;}#mermaid-1671893404869 .edgeTerminals{font-size:11px;}#mermaid-1671893404869 :root{--mermaid-font-family:"trebuchet ms",verdana,arial,sans-serif;}
    </style>
    <g>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="240" markerWidth="190" refY="7" refX="0" class="marker aggregation classDiagram" id="classDiagram-aggregationStart">
                <path d="M 18,7 L9,13 L1,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="28" markerWidth="20" refY="7" refX="19" class="marker aggregation classDiagram" id="classDiagram-aggregationEnd">
                <path d="M 18,7 L9,13 L1,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="240" markerWidth="190" refY="7" refX="0" class="marker extension classDiagram" id="classDiagram-extensionStart">
                <path d="M 1,7 L18,13 V 1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="28" markerWidth="20" refY="7" refX="19" class="marker extension classDiagram" id="classDiagram-extensionEnd">
                <path d="M 1,1 V 13 L18,7 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="240" markerWidth="190" refY="7" refX="0" class="marker composition classDiagram" id="classDiagram-compositionStart">
                <path d="M 18,7 L9,13 L1,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="28" markerWidth="20" refY="7" refX="19" class="marker composition classDiagram" id="classDiagram-compositionEnd">
                <path d="M 18,7 L9,13 L1,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="240" markerWidth="190" refY="7" refX="0" class="marker dependency classDiagram" id="classDiagram-dependencyStart">
                <path d="M 5,7 L9,13 L1,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="28" markerWidth="20" refY="7" refX="19" class="marker dependency classDiagram" id="classDiagram-dependencyEnd">
                <path d="M 18,7 L9,13 L14,7 L9,1 Z">
                </path>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <marker orient="auto" markerHeight="240" markerWidth="190" refY="7" refX="0" class="marker lollipop classDiagram" id="classDiagram-lollipopStart">
                <circle r="6" cy="7" cx="6" fill="white" stroke="black">
                </circle>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <g class="root">
            <g class="clusters">
            </g>
            <g class="edgePaths">
                <path marker-end="url(#classDiagram-extensionEnd)" marker-start="url(#classDiagram-extensionStart)" style="fill:none" class="edge-pattern-solid relation" id="id1" d="M58.962245118973726,72.59658813476562L55.24552626440763,76.7632548014323C51.528807409841534,80.92992146809895,44.09536970070934,89.2632548014323,40.378650846143245,97.59658813476562C36.66193199157715,105.92992146809895,36.66193199157715,114.2632548014323,36.66193199157715,118.42992146809895L36.66193199157715,122.59658813476562">
                </path>
                <path marker-end="url(#classDiagram-extensionEnd)" marker-start="url(#classDiagram-extensionStart)" style="fill:none" class="edge-pattern-solid relation" id="id2" d="M116.58321081364346,72.59658813476562L120.29992966820957,76.7632548014323C124.01664852277565,80.92992146809895,131.45008623190785,89.2632548014323,135.16680508647394,97.59658813476562C138.88352394104004,105.92992146809895,138.88352394104004,114.2632548014323,138.88352394104004,118.42992146809895L138.88352394104004,122.59658813476562">
                </path>
            </g>
            <g class="edgeLabels">
                <g class="edgeLabel">
                    <g transform="translate(0, 0)" class="label">
                        <foreignObject height="0" width="0">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="edgeLabel">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g class="edgeLabel">
                    <g transform="translate(0, 0)" class="label">
                        <foreignObject height="0" width="0">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="edgeLabel">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g class="nodes">
                <g transform="translate(87.7727279663086, 40.29829406738281)" id="classid-Animal-0" class="node default">
                    <rect height="64.59659194946289" width="66.34659194946289" y="-32.298295974731445" x="-33.173295974731445" class="outer title-state">
                    </rect>
                    <line y2="5.298295974731445" y1="5.298295974731445" x2="33.173295974731445" x1="-33.173295974731445" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <line y2="21.298295974731445" y1="21.298295974731445" x2="33.173295974731445" x1="-33.173295974731445" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <g class="label">
                        <foreignObject height="0" width="0">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                        <foreignObject transform="translate( -25.673295974731445, -24.798295974731445)" height="25.59659194946289" width="51.34659194946289" class="classTitle">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                    Animal
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(36.66193199157715, 154.89488220214844)" id="classid-Zebra-1" class="node default conceal">
                    <rect height="64.59659194946289" width="57.3238639831543" y="-32.298295974731445" x="-28.66193199157715" class="outer title-state">
                    </rect>
                    <line y2="5.298295974731445" y1="5.298295974731445" x2="28.66193199157715" x1="-28.66193199157715" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <line y2="21.298295974731445" y1="21.298295974731445" x2="28.66193199157715" x1="-28.66193199157715" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <g class="label">
                        <foreignObject height="0" width="0">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                        <foreignObject transform="translate( -21.16193199157715, -24.798295974731445)" height="25.59659194946289" width="42.3238639831543" class="classTitle">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                    Zebra
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(138.88352394104004, 154.89488220214844)" id="classid-Lion-2" class="node default">
                    <rect height="64.59659194946289" width="47.119319915771484" y="-32.298295974731445" x="-23.559659957885742" class="outer title-state">
                    </rect>
                    <line y2="5.298295974731445" y1="5.298295974731445" x2="23.559659957885742" x1="-23.559659957885742" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <line y2="21.298295974731445" y1="21.298295974731445" x2="23.559659957885742" x1="-23.559659957885742" class="divider">
                    </line>
                    <g class="label">
                        <foreignObject height="0" width="0">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                        <foreignObject transform="translate( -16.059659957885742, -24.798295974731445)" height="25.59659194946289" width="32.119319915771484" class="classTitle">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                                <span class="nodeLabel">
                                    Lion
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </foreignObject>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### Question:

Is there a way using CSS selectors to apply the reduced opacity to only one of the edgePaths?